# Destroy action in RSpec test not returning success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a Rails 5 application that creates and destroys "csstests." I am attempting to write a test for the controllers destroy action. Here is the action:

```
def destroy 
    @test = Csstest.find(params[:id])
    if @test.destroy
        flash.now[:success] = "Your test was removed"
        redirect_to csstests_path 
    end 
end
```

Here is the RSpec test:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do 

    before do 
        test1, test2 = Csstest.create, Csstest.create
        delete :destroy, params: { id: test1.id }
    end

    it 'returns HTTP success' do 
        expect(response).to be_success
        expect(response).to return_http_status(200)
    end

end
```

This is the message I get from the failure:

```
1) CsstestsController DELETE #destroy returns HTTP success
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
   expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fb1362beb68 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mu...spatch::Http::Headers:0x007fb1362de4b8 @req=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x007fb1362becf8 ...>>>>.success?` to return true, got false
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the basics of [HTTP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) - in particular:

- `2xx` responses are "success" status codes.
- `3xx` responses are "redirection" status codes.

In your controller, you have chosen to perform a **redirect** if the `Csstest` record is deleted: `redirect_to csstests_path`.

If this is truly the desired behaviour, then you could update your `rspec` test to expect this:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(csstests_path)
# This second assertion is probably not really necessary
# But I'll leave it here for completion...
expect(response).to return_http_status(302)
```

It is also possible to explicitly return `301` or `303` status codes for the redirect (see [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)). But again, these will not be considered "success" codes.